# Remote Desktop Grapic/Menu Weirdness

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, desktop, boot-camp

I am having issues with remote desktop in Windows 10 on a MacBook Pro 15" Retina in Boot Camp. I have included a link with an image of my desktop showing the issues, but they are:

- Start button is not visible but clickable
- Clicking a program with multiple open windows shows a weird list
  without the usual information regarding the individual windows
- Task tray icon is not visible but clickable
- Clicking the file explorer icon does not open a file explorer window
- Date is not visible but clickable
- Right click menu in explorer shows a menu that is not usable - it
  cuts off most of the menu (image overlayed within desktop image
  because I can not display the stacked menu and right click menu at
  the same time)

These issues do not present themselves if I use RD within OS X, or on other Windows machines. It seems to be just in Boot Camp on this MacBook. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I had logged out and back in several times previously, I had not tried logging in with a different PC and then back in with the MacBook.

It looks like that's all I needed to do because it's no longer happening.